# pthread nice value setting for default scheduler in C

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I was trying to set the nice values using setpriority for threads but cannot seem to get it to work in the correct fashion. Whenever I do a get priority the value always turns up as -1. So basically I am not able to set any of the nice values in anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

static int var = 0;

void *my_inc()
{
    setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, pthread_self(), -10);
    printf("thread 1 within  %d \n", getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, pthread_self()));
    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var = i;
        sleep(1);
        printf("hi ");
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);    
}

void *my_print()
{    
    while(1)
    {
        printf("var %d\n", var);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread_id1, thread_id2, thread_id3;

    pthread_create(&thread_id1, NULL, my_inc, NULL);
    printf("thread 1 before %d \n", getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, thread_id1));
    setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, thread_id1, -10);      

    pthread_create(&thread_id3, NULL, my_print, NULL);    
    setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, thread_id3, 10);

    printf("thread 3 after %d \n", getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, thread_id3));
    printf("thread 1 after %d \n", getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, thread_id1));

    for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        printf("main %d ", j);
        sleep(1);
    }

    pthread_join(thread_id1, NULL);
    exit(0); 
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    printf("After thread\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear to me what makes you think the [`setpriority()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setpriority) function would be in any way applicable to the task you are attempting to perform.  From its docs:

> The `setpriority()` function shall set the nice value of a process, process group, or user [...].

A thread is none of those.

Moreover,

> *who* is interpreted relative to *which* (a process identifier for
>   `PRIO_PROCESS`, process group identifier for `PRIO_PGRP`, and a user ID
>   for `PRIO_USER`).

You are specifying `PRIO_PROCESS` and passing a thread identifier, but a thread identifier is not a process id.  `pthread_t` is not even required to be an integer type, unlike `pid_t`.  It is not surprising, therefore, that `setpriority()` fails, returning -1 and setting `errno` appropriately.  You would know that this was happening if you were properly checking your function call results for error codes.

Perhaps you can achieve your objective via the [`pthread_setschedprio()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_setschedprio) function, instead.

Comment: From what I have read threads maintain a diffrent nice value. From my uinderstanding setschedprio wont do much for the default schedeuler which doesn't have a priority level. So I was trying to figure out a way to use the default scheduler and keep different niceness values to create a more tiered system if necessary.

Comment: No, @DBB,  threads do have per-thread scheduling properties, but that's separate from niceness. Threads do not have their own nice values at all. It is a property (in different, but related, senses) only of processes, process groups, and users.  If you want something finer grained than that then perhaps the default scheduler is not suited to your requirements.

Comment: I see, so in effect I can set a FIFO or RR and use the setschedprio above. Thanks for your help will look into that

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting -1, you probably have an error:  From **man 2 getpriority:**

```
   On success, getpriority() returns the calling thread's nice value,
   which may be a negative number.  **On error, it returns -1 and sets
   errno to indicate the cause of the error.**  Since a successful call to
   getpriority() can legitimately return the value -1, it is necessary
   to clear the external variable errno prior to the call, then check it
   afterward to determine if -1 is an error or a legitimate value.
```

Also:  in my experience, "nicenecess" does not have much effect.  If you have a process that is CPU-intensive *(likely to consume entire time-slices without pausing for I/O ...),* it is "courteous" to assign that process a nice-value that will encourage the scheduler to put it in the background.  But modern schedulers are generally much smarter and more aware than their predecessors were anyhow.  They generally make that determination on their own without need for a hint.

Comment: I was thinking of creating a weigthed scheduling like have the main process get more weigth compared to other threads. I was trying to see if it was possible using the default scheduler to change the nice values of threads.I was able to find very little resources for threads and now I am just curious on how to do it.